# How to get rid of lettering in the sectioning?

Tags: latex

Using article class, and I wonder how do i change sectioning from letters to numbers? (pic attached). Preferable to have sections as integers, and subsections as 1.1 , 1.1.1 etc... if section is 1. (so 1 instead of A. in the picture)

Similar code for a different article generates roman numerals, so not sure what's at play here. But I wonder if numbering from ijmart class is possible to do in article class in short.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` should do the trick. In order to change the subsection format, do `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}` and so on.

From what I know, `article` class has arabic enumerations set as standard, though. Mind sharing a reproducible example if the above lines don't fix the issue?

Comment: Ok, let me try and see.... yeah that's the issue I was really surprised and couldn't find anything i could change in the code to counter act that.

Comment: Yeah so the correction didn't work however simply using {ijmart} class is sufficient in this case. But it's quite confusing as in another article it simply puts roman numerals in. 

anyways, thanks for help!

Comment: Do you mind sharing a reproducible example? I'd like to play with this a bit myself